# R remove first row from write,csv

Tags: r, csv

I need to write to csv without the columns names row.
The following snippet:

```
 CSAT <- data[j,1]  
 Verbatim <- data[j,2] 
 write.csv (Verbatim, paste(CSAT,'.csv',sep = ""), row.names=FALSE)
```

CSAT is a variable containing dynamic value 
(changes in runtime) for the file name.

write data to csv, but the the csv looks like this (2 rows instead of desired 1 row):

"x"

"I am very disappointed in your service. I had been with xxxxx for 9 years and even though I had problems a few times I knew they would look after me as a customer. I can't say the same about yyyyy. Only been with you 6 months and already feel let down by "

Where did "x" came from? it's not part of the data..
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot turn off `col.names` with `write.csv` because `CSV` files require them. So if if your data doesn't have headers, `write.csv` will add them. That's where the "x" came from. Try using the more robust `write.table`

```
write.table(Verbatim, paste(CSAT), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```